# C#: Using WriteError and WriteVerbose in non-cmdlet inheriting class

Tags: c#, powershell

Apologies for the seemingly odd Title on this.  I'm creating some PowerShell modules in C# and I'm getting rather stuck on the above.  In BeginProcessing, ProcessRecord etc, I can call WriteWarning, WriterError and WriteVerbose.  However, if I want to add Warnings, Errors etc to any of my custom classes, which are instantiated in the above, then I cannot call these because they're not inheriting from cmdlet.  I've spent ages searching for an answer on this, but I cannot find the answer.  I found an msdn  blog post that wrote about this, but they just called these from within ProcessRecord.

I'm guessing I need to send the messages back to ProcessMessage using a pipeline, but I don't understand how I should do this.  Can anybody give me any tips on what/how I should be doing ?

Comment: `WriteWarning`, `WriterError`, `WriteVerbose` are public methods. You do not need to inherit from `Cmdlet` to call them.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a Func/delegate of the method(s) that you need to your other custom classes. Ideally you want to wrap all of that up in your own ILogger class that you then implement and pass on to your classes. Or you could just pass the class itself to your other custom classes since the methods that you want to call on it are public.